# what is the circle at the right of my toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

I add toolbar to my layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and I initialized it in mainActivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

but at my toolbar was appeared a circle at the right of my toolbar! I also have removed logo and title from toolbar but I still see this circle and it wont be disappear!! 
[image]

What is it? and how can I remove that?
thank you

Comment: I might be wrong but u have used ProgressBar inside Toolbar in xml. That's why u r getting that?

Comment: yes but it visibility is gone and not to be shown yet.for loading some stuff I am using this progressbar.

Comment: Try to set `progress_spinner` visibility to `GONE` by code.

Comment: Try to use this `ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible)` when you loading some stuff

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana I have removed progressbar from my xml layout but this circle still is shown.

Comment: Try to use "Layout inspector" to find out what this view is and post it. See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana it was because actionmenuview https://imgur.com/a/KEU9A. thankyou for helping.

Comment: Glad I helped. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you said that removing the `ProgressBar` from the layout doesn't hide it, and because of the position, it could be a menu. Are you overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Also, as I said in my comment, try to use "Layout inspector" to find out what this view is. See [developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html](http://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html)

Comment: I use layout-inspector and find out my problem was because of `Action menu view`.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with programmatic Progress Bar view visible and gone

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);

progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I have removed progressbar from my xml layout but this circle still is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add what you have written in this style ??

```
@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay
```